# What's the correct way to have webapp logs in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are developing an application based on Azure webapps and are having troubles understanding how to get basic logs from them. There seems to be at least 3 different ways to get some logs:

- I can access Kudu (?) logs using URL https://my-webapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/
- I should be able to access the same (?) logs using `az webapp log` but when I use `show` command it says no logs are activated
- I can also access some logs using the `Diagnose and Solve Problems` menu in the Azure UI but that's cumbersome

What I would like is very simply to be able to do a `tail` on logs on a running webapp and get all logs that are generated by it, whether it be HTTP request logs from the hosting HTTP server, system logs or applicative level logs.

Can someone point me at the right documents explaining what's the correct way to do that?

Comment: just to be sure ...can you review if you're contributor on the resource group? You should be able to view Kudu with no problems. Also, double check if the logs are enabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs

Comment: Thanks @ThiagoCustodio I can definitely view Kudu logs, it's just that it's not clear to me whether this is the "right" way to configure/use logging in Azure.